# Interval censored Cox proportional hazards model in R

Tags: r, survival, cox-model, interval-censoring

Given interval censored survival times, how do I perform an interval censored Cox PH model in `R`? An rseek search turns up the package `intcox`, which no longer exists in the `R` repository. I'm almost positive the `coxph` function in the `survival` package cannot handle interval censored survival data.

Also, I don't want to impute the data and then use the `coxph` function. This method underestimates the standard errors of the coefficients because you are ignoring the uncertainty of the interval censoring.

Comment: You can still install the `intcox` package even if it's not on `CRAN` using the normal `install.packages("intcox")`.

Comment: Hmmm... I was not able to do that. Could the mirror selection affect the download?

Comment: It's possible, but I don't know. I just used the Berlin CRAN to do it about 10 minutes ago (R version 2.15.1).

Comment: The [Survival Analysis CRAN Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Survival.html) summarizes available packages for survival analysis, including a number with support for interval censoring.

Comment: As of 21 Dec 2015, I was able to `install.packages("intcox")` without any particular trouble (R-devel, but any modern R should work)

Answer (score 11):

As stated above, you can use the survreg function. A note though: this is not strictly a Cox PH model, but rather location-scale models. Using the default log-transformation, this is the aft model. In the case of the exponential distribution, the proportional hazards and aft model are equivalent, so if distribution is set to exponential, this is a proportional hazards model with an exponential baseline. Likewise, if a baseline Weibull distribution aft model is used, the parameter estimates are just a linear transformation of those used in the proportional hazards model
 with Weibull baseline distribution. But in general, survreg does not fit a Cox PH model.

If a semi-parametric model is desired, as found implemented in intcox, a word of caution: there are several issues with the current version of intcox (algorithm typically prematurely terminates significantly far from the MLE, fails outright with uncensored observations, no standard errors automatically presented).

A new alternative that you could use is the package "icenReg".

Admission of bias: this is the author of icenReg.

Comment: Welcome to our site!  We're glad to have you and your fine contributions.

Comment: @Cliff AB What specific semi-parametric method do you use in the ic_sp function? Do you have a paper or tutorial about the method?

Comment: @Munichong: the full paper can be found [here](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v081i12/v81i12.pdf). Alternatively, the package's vignette gives a quick introduction to the models as well; see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/icenReg/vignettes/icenReg.pdf)

Comment: @CliffAB Since my data is too large to fit in the memory, I want to modify ic_sp in a stochastic way: Feed a mini-batch to ic_sp and set maxIter = 1, get the gradients and update betas iteratively. Do you know How I can access the gradients from the ic_sp function?

Comment: @Munichong: interesting! Unfortunately, I don't think this method will work. In particular, `ic_sp` needs to estimate the baseline survival distribution (unlike in right censored case), which has as many parameters as unique times in your data. This creates a problem for mini-batching; with continuous times, the baseline steps will not line up batch to batch.

Comment: Something like a parametric approach, in which the baseline distribution is parameterized by 2 fixed parameters, would likely work. Unfortunately, in `icenReg`, all the derivatives are computed at the C++ level and are not readily accessible in R.

Answer (score 1):

To do interval censored analysis in R, you must create a Surv object, and then use survfit(). If you have more than a variable, the intcox package solves the problem.