# Cox Proportional Hazards regression where event is most likely to occur at set intervals

Tags: survival, cox-model, proportional-hazards

I'm interested in evaluating the effect of various factors on the lifespan of borrower-lender relationships using a Cox Time-Varying Proportional Hazards regression.

However, as the relationships we observe are defined by the existence of a loan filing which covers a 5-year span (the loan can be terminated early, extended, or a follow-up loan filed), the relationships are **most likely** to end at the 5 year mark (or at least in 5-year intervals).  Does this present a potential complication for a Cox Proportional Hazards model, or is the framework able to properly account for situations like this where there's a pattern in when an event might occur?

Basically, is it a problem for a CPH regression that the base time component possibly follows a relatively fixed interval?

Comment: For some guidance, see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/45745/64263

Answer (score 1):

A Cox model can have problems with multiple tied event times, as outlined [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/577028/28500). The exact correction for ties can be computationally expensive. The Efron and Breslow approximations don't work well when most of the events happen at the same time.

If you had a limited number of fixed intervals then a discrete-time survival model would be appropriate. It seems, however, that other events can happen at any time during the standard 5-year window.

For either a Cox model or a discrete-time model, you need to decide whether you think that the associations of covariates with the risk of ending the borrower-lender relationship are the same for each type of termination. This might be handled better with a competing-risks model, maybe a Markov multi-state model, that allows for differences in baseline hazards and in covariate associations and that can accommodate both continuous and discrete event times. I don't have experience with those, but the R [`rstpm2` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rstpm2) seems to provide the necessary tools.